# Match multiple condition on large dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have below mentioned two dataframe:

DF_1

```
Val1           Val2
COPPAR Ert     Metal          
Bittar Gourd   vegetble
Blackbery d    Fruite
```

DF_2

```
Val4           Val5        Type
Copper         Metal       A-I   
Bitter Gourd   Vegetable   B-II
Blackberry     Fruit       C-III
```

I have some error in `DF_1` in `Val1` and `Val2` (Where same like string in `Val1` and `Val2` are different in spelling) and have the correct list in `DF_2`. Just want to Match `Val1` of DF_1 with `Val4` of DF_2 and based on the correct value (`New_Val1`) I want the `Val5` in `New_Val2` and `Type`, in the output dataframe.

Output Dataframe:

```
Val1           Val2      New_Val1       New_Val2    Type
COPPAR         Metal     Copper Ert     Metal       A-I      
Bittar Gourd   vegetble  Bitter Gourd   Vegetable   B-II
Blackbery      Fruite    Blackberry     Fruit       C-III
```

Comment: you can using soundex

Comment: @Wen What is that...??I have never used.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phonics/phonics.pdf

Comment: @Wen Thanks, can you please suggest me how can i use this on my large dataframe with the conditions that  i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yep adding an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is base on soundex

```
library(phonics)

df1['match1']=soundex(df1$Val1)
df1['match2']=soundex(df1$Val2)
df2['match1']=soundex(df2$Val4)
df2['match2']=soundex(df2$Val5)
merge(df1,df2,by=c('match1','match2'))
  match1 match2         Val1     Val2         Val4      Val5  Type
1   B360   V231 Bittar Gourd vegetble Bitter Gourd Vegetable  B-II
2   B421   F630  Blackbery d   Fruite   Blackberry     Fruit C-III
3   C160   M340   COPPAR Ert    Metal       Copper     Metal   A-I
```